# How to calculate the sum of each element of an array and its previous elements in JavaScript？

Tags: javascript

For example, if I have an array [1,2,3,4], I want to calculate 1+2, 1+2+3 and 1+2+3+4 and return a new array. How can I do that?

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

doSomething(arr);

output...

newArr = [1, 3, 6, 10];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This would be a good exercise to practise your skills

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the array for getting the wanted elements and reduce the value for getting a sum.

Methods:

- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new array of the sum,
- [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a part of the array,
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for adding all values.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    sums = array.map((_, i, a) => a.slice(0, i + 1).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
    
console.log(sums);
```

Fun with a closure over the sum

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    sums = array.map((a => b => a += b)(0));
    
console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this function.

```
function dosomething (arr) {
  var i;
  if(i === 1 || i === 0) return arr; 
  for(i = 1; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] += arr[i-1];
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use array.reduce

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let newArr = [];

arr.reduce((prev, current) => {newArr.push(prev+current); return prev + current}, 0);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some elegant method:

```js
function getArrSum(arr)
{
    if(!arr.length) return [];
    let tmp=[arr[0]];
    for(let i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        tmp.push(tmp[i-1]+arr[i]);
    }
    return tmp;
}
let arr=[1,2,3,4];
console.log(getArrSum(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var a = [1,2,3,4];
 var b=[];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{   

  var sum = 0;

  for(j=0;j<=i+1;j++)
  {
    if(a[j] != null)
        sum=sum+a[j];
  }    
  b[i]=sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the array is:

```js
function getArray(numbers)
{
    if(!numbers.length) return [];
    let array=[numbers[0]];
    for(let i=1; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        array.push(array[i-1]+numbers[i]);
    }
    return array;
}
let array=[1,2,3,4];
let procArray = [];
console.log(getArray(array));
```